# Elasticsearch Bulk API - Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to bulk import using a POST request to `localhost:9200/products/product/_bulk` with the following JSON:

```
[
  { "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 1} },
  { "title": "Product A","description": "Brand A - Product A - 1.5 kg","price": 3.49,"sku": "wi208564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand A\n"},
  { "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 2} },
  { "title": "Product B","description": "Brand B - Product B - 1 kg","price": 2.49,"sku": "wi308564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand B\n"},
  { "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 3} },
  { "title": "Product C","description": "Brand C - Product C - 2.5 kg","price": 4.49,"sku": "wi108564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand C\n"}
]
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{
"error": "JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: [B@2c1e2b0e; line: 1, column: 0])\ at [Source: [B@2c1e2b0e; line: 1, column: 3]]",
"status": 500
}
```

I've tried changing the JSON format but it didn't help. What seems to be going wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your formatting isn't quite right: for bulk request, individual items are separated by newline characters (not commas) and there are no square brackets at the end (ie the payload is a sequence of JSON documents, but the whole payload is not itself a valid json document)

Your data should look like

```
{ "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 1} }
{ "title": "Product A","description": "Brand A - Product A - 1.5 kg","price": 3.49,"sku": "wi208564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand A\n"}
{ "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 2} }
{ "title": "Product B","description": "Brand B - Product B - 1 kg","price": 2.49,"sku": "wi308564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand B\n"}
```

Comment: newline is required at end of json

Comment: Do we need to add `{ "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 1} } ` line before each document?