# Cannot Create Mapping and Add data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Everytime I follow the instruction about Create Index, Mapping and Add Data in elasticsearch i have the error.
I'm using Postman.
First of all, i create index:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/schools
```

(actually, i have to use put to create succesfully)

Next, i create Mapping and Add Data:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/schools/_bulk
```

Request Body

```
    {
       "index":{
          "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1"
       }
    }
    {
       "name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan",
       "city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location":[31.8955385, 76.8380405],
       "fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5"
    }
    {
       "index":{
          "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"2"
       }
    }
    {
       "name":"Saint Paul School", "description":"ICSE 
       Afiliation", "street":"Dawarka", "city":"Delhi", "state":"Delhi", "zip":"110075",
       "location":[28.5733056, 77.0122136], "fees":5000,
       "tags":["Good Faculty", "Great Sports"], "rating":"4.5"
    }
    {
       "index":{"_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"3"}
    }
    {
       "name":"Crescent School", "description":"State Board Affiliation", "street":"Tonk Road", 
       "city":"Jaipur", "state":"RJ", "zip":"176114","location":[26.8535922, 75.7923988],
       "fees":2500, "tags":["Well equipped labs"], "rating":"4.5"
    }
```

But all i receive is just:

```
   {
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "json_e_o_f_exception",
            "reason": "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@681c6189; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@681c6189; line: 2, column: 3]"
          }
        ],
        "type": "json_e_o_f_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@681c6189; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@681c6189; line: 2, column: 3]"
      },
      "status": 500
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your request body JSON is malformed. I'd advise checking with just one entry until you can get it into Elasticsearch, then add the others.

The following JSON is valid, though I'm not sure if it provides the structure you want:

```
{
   "index":{
      "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1"
   },
   "name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan",
   "city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location":[31.8955385, 76.8380405],
   "fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5"
}
```

You can use a tool for formatting and validating JSON to make sure it is valid JSON. Below are some examples.

http://jsonformatter.org/

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: This is wrong. The bulk insert api doesn't take correctly formed json objects, rather a line-separated list of json objects.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. it should be:
`{ "index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1"} }
{"name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan", "city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location":[31.8955385, 76.8380405], "fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5 \n"} `

Using newlines to separate each document you're posting to ES. If you want to check that this works first, then I'll edit my answer to reflect this. Sorry that the formatting in comments isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

I see something which similar to my problem. My problem solved!

[Elasticsearch Bulk API - Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457887/elasticsearch-bulk-api-unexpected-end-of-input-expected-close-marker-for-arra)

Answer (score 1):

To load data to Elasticsearch, use the REST API endpoint is '/_bulk' which expects
the following **newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) structure**:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

**The Curl request example:**
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'elasticsearchhost:port/index-name-sample/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @sample.json

In your case, the request will be as follows:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/schools/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @schools-sample.json

The schools-sample.json content:

```
{"index":{"_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1"}}
{"name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan","city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location":[31.8955385, 76.8380405],"fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5"}
{"index":{"_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"2"}}
{"name":"Saint Paul School", "description":"ICSE Afiliation", "street":"Dawarka", "city":"Delhi", "state":"Delhi", "zip":"110075","location":[28.5733056, 77.0122136], "fees":5000,"tags":["Good Faculty", "Great Sports"], "rating":"4.5"}
/n
```

**Important**: the final line of data must end with a newline character \n. Each newline character may be preceded by a carriage return \r. Otherwise, you will get an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "index":{"_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1" }}
{ "name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan",  "city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location":[31.8955385, 76.8380405],  "fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5\n"}
{ "index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"2"  }}
{ "name":"Saint Paul School", "description":"ICSE Afiliation", "street":"Dawarka", "city":"Delhi", "state":"Delhi", "zip":"110075","location":[28.5733056, 77.0122136], "fees":5000,"tags":["Good Faculty", "Great Sports"], "rating":"4.5\n" }
{ "index":{"_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"3"}}
{ "name":"Crescent School", "description":"State Board Affiliation", "street":"Tonk Road", "city":"Jaipur", "state":"RJ", "zip":"176114","location":[26.8535922, 75.7923988],"fees":2500, "tags":["Well equipped labs"], "rating":"4.5\n"}
```