# Elastic search bulk api - Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, curl, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to upload a json data into elastic search api and trying using curl command, but when i try, getting this kind of error.

Error reason

```
"reason": "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 2, column: 1]"
```

Command:

```
curl -XPOST -u dev-user:dev-user-password domain-endpoint/_bulk https://search-****.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_bulk --data-binary @sample.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

sample.json

```
{ "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 1} }
{ "title": "Product A","description": "Brand A - Product A - 1.5 kg","price": 3.49,"sku": "wi208564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand A\n"}
{ "index": {"_index": "products", "_type": "product", "_id": 2} }
{ "title": "Product B","description": "Brand B - Product B - 1 kg","price": 2.49,"sku": "wi308564","supermarket": "AJ","categories": "Fruit AJ","product_type": "Sinaasappels - mandarijnen","brand": "Brand B\n"}
```

I tried the solution posted here, [Elasticsearch Bulk API - Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457887/elasticsearch-bulk-api-unexpected-end-of-input-expected-close-marker-for-arra) but still getting the same error.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: please ensure that you added an empty line at the end of your Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an empty line at the end of the json resolved the issue.